# How to design database tables for complex build of materials as product models?

Tags: database, rules-engine

I need to redesign a 10 year old Product Management Portal and underlying Data-model. There are build of materials as products in the system.

Product managers update pricing frequently for products. The current system uses Textual Boolean expression typed-in a Text-area, using combination of attributes of materials. It results in long lines of && and || expression.

The attributes are also conditional i.e. one attribute depends on other attributes using similar Boolean expression approach. The validity of applicable attributes and price gets calculated using recursive expression evaluation engine, which I believe is slow and not so effective approach.

I want to alter this approach to a more user interactive approach as well as direct and fast calculation of price.

Can any one, who has tackled variable pricing based on combination of multiple price tags and specification attributes, i.e for (height > 10 inch, color = red) price is $50, for (height > 10 inch, color = white) price is $53 and for (height < 10 inch, sleeve = False) price is $23?

It shall also support the different kind of price for applicable tags and attributes i.e. the value can be a multiplier (1.5 times or 0.3 times), the value can be additional cost ($23 or -$10), or the value can have both multiplier and 'to add' components.

I need to be cautious with my design as I will also need to support existing business logic and applications, till all the applications are overhauled and modified around new data-model.

Comment: One of my first jobs was writing a series of SQL queries to re-jigger Bills of Materials for various configurations of memory devices so that, on a given day, the devices could be built with the cheapest memory chips.  The existing MRP system was not capable of this level of granularity.  IIRC it took 30 queries to accomplish.

Comment: If performance is slow, can you not cache the result until the specification changes? There isn't really enough information here to say how you should proceed, and you don't explain why you need to redesign the system.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood reminds me of Joel's blog post about rewriting software https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/

Comment: Thank you, George. I can implement cache and design keys to maintain, but at the moment it is not there. Now, since there is need of work on it, I like to overhaul the changes with best possible architecture solution. And, this is the first step in that direction, hence I want to learn from others experiences and wits.. Nonetheless, I intend to use cache, when I start revamping existing desktop application and creating new multi-platform apps.

Comment: Thanks @binnyb, nice article on rewriting code from scratch. Let me see, if I can avoid that mistake.. :)

Comment: *"which I believe is slow and not so effective approach."* - so you just **believe** this, but did not make any performance measurements to see if this is really a bottleneck? And what do the PMs say, do they have any issues using  current system of defining the prices?

Comment: @DocBrown clearly Hitesh hasn't been here long enough ;)

Comment: Thanks @DocBrown, for suggesting performance measurements. I have not yet measured them. Not yet.. when I check the numbers, how will I get to know which solution is better, if there is at the moment only one solution? As, there is no alternative solution, relative performance & numbers can't be compared. I need to try a solution and measure it against existing and then convince my management team to implement/keep the better one..

Comment: @HiteshGaur: for example, if a certain calculation run takes a minute in total, and your users are not satisfied by this, you should measure the individual parts of the calculation. If it turns out the price expression evaluation is just a small part and takes less than a second of the minute, trying to optimize there would be a waste of time. If, however, the expression evaluation takes >55 seconds, it should not be hard to convince management you need to search for a better approach.

Comment: I understand @DocBrown. The system has been there for last 3 years, and over the years multiple applications have been introduced, where these apps Desktop/Console/API/DLLS are consuming the engine/evaluator, so it's been working. I guess, users were satisfied earlier with creating long Boolean expression in Text Area, but now it's becoming unmanageable for them, which should have been expected. So, I need to start with a Proof of Concept. Based on your advice, I may keep price evaluator. I still welcome ideas from others and learn from there experience regarding Bills of Materials and pricing

Comment: @RobertHarvey, binnyb, GeorgeBarwood and DocBrown. I will also welcome, if there are any existing apps, libraries or engines that deal with such Bills of Materials and dynamic pricing, as reinventing the wheel would be waste of time. If there is something, I will gladly look at it, and try to integrate it. Thank you.

Comment: @HiteshGaur: your comment just confirmed my suspicion: you should not ask for "fast" solution, you should ask for a more convenient solution for the users - which is a very different one than the one you asked. Maybe you could extend the expression language to make it more powerful, so users can write down even fairly complex price definitions using shorter (and more manageable) formulas?

Comment: Thanks @DocBrown, I understand. That's why I had placed it at the end of sentence, it is secondary/less weighted criteria. The primary feature is easier user interaction then Text Area and Boolean expression. But, it doesn't mean that I need not to change database design. That also needs attention, because of presence of redundancy in bulk.

Comment: @HiteshGaur: I would actually invest **zero** thoughts into performance as long as there are no measurable performance problems. And since you asked for existing apps: many companies utilize spreadsheets for this. Either as stand-alone solutions, or just for something like a pric definition in conjunction with a bigger system.

Comment: Thanks @Doc Brown, I agree, it is very common that most users use and maintain spreadsheets. The existing users for this system also use spreadsheets. It is pretty common these days that most of applications need to have import and export features because of widespread use of spread sheets. I expect those feature for the new system/UI as-well. It does not mean that spreadsheet is always easy to use, and it does not mean that I do not need to give them an easy to use UI.